# Apply StandardScaler to 3D Array and omit values

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a 3D Scaler (samples,rows,columns) that I would like to apply a StandardScaler. Because it is 3D, I was planning on using this:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1, X_train.shape[-1])).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.reshape(-1, X_test.shape[-1])).reshape(X_test.shape)
```

The problem is that the rows are padded with special values (-100) and applying the scalar on the data as is would be incorrect because the padded values influence the scaler. Is there a way to omit the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `-100` to `np.NaN` and ignore the NaNs.

AFAIK, `StandardScaler()` can not ignore NaNs.

Because this is simple scaling of `(x-mean)/std`, you can do it by yourself by `np.nanmean()` and `np.nanstd()`.
Then you can return the NaN to -100.

However, take into account that this -100 will affect the rest of your calculation pipeline (I guess you have something after the scaling), so you need to resolve it anyway.